# Can I format an URL to launch Safari from within my app's UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

My app has a UIWebView that shows a fair amount of content. For some of that content I would like to exit the app, and launch Safari to handle the web content rather than doing it in my UIWebView. Is there an url format that will explicitly launch Safari rather than loading a page in the UIWebView?

Obviously I can't use http:// since that just opens the url in place. Can I use safari:// or something of the sort?

EDIT: Apologies, I wasn't clear originally. I am looking for a solution that involves changing urls on pages without making modifications to my client. Hoping for a native Safari launching pattern along the lines of tel:// for the phone.

Answer (score 5):

Sure.  Then just have the `UIWebView` delegate do:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
  NSString * customScheme = @"safari";

  NSURL * loadURL = [request URL];  //this is the url the user tapped
  if ([[loadURL scheme] isEqual:customScheme]) {
    //if the url starts with "safari://"
    NSString * absoluteURL = [loadURL absoluteString];
    //replace "safari" with "https"
    absoluteURL = [absoluteURL stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,[customScheme length]) withString:@"https"];
    NSURL * openURL = [NSURL URLWithString:absoluteURL];
    //open the URL in MobileSafari
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:openURL];
    //tell your UIWebView to ignore this request
    return NO;
  } else {
    //this is not a safari:// url, so handle it normally
    return YES;
  }
}
```

Comment: Must the scheme be replaced with `https://` and not `http://` for it to launch Safari correctly? Does the web view interfere otherwise?

Comment: @BoltClock I just picked `https` arbitrarily.  If you wanted to support both `safari://` and `safaris://` URLs, then you could check the `[loadURL scheme]` for both variants, but leave the replacement bit the same.  Or you could do some sort of dictionary to map the intercepted scheme (the key) to the scheme that MobileSafari should use (the value)

Comment: You could also leave the `http://`/`https://` in the URL and just strip the `safari://` instead of replacing it.

Comment: @Cory i'm not sure that the `UIWebView` would parse that correctly, but if it does, that'd be pretty awesome.  Or perhaps you could do a scheme like `safari-http://` or `safari-https://` and just strip off `safari-` (or heck:  `external-http://`)

Comment: Ahh sorry guys, I wasn't clear in my question. I'm looking for a way to do this without modifying my client. So wondering if there is a native shortcut to safari like there is to tel:// etc.

Comment: @MahatmaManic ah in that case, no.  If this is functionality you'd like, please file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com